# Nested queries in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have issues on nested queries I'm trying to do using firebase, seems like the first query (activity1) doesn't wait until the second (activity2) and third query (activity3) finished running, this might return NULL value from the first query. Please look at my sample for more understanding, I've been stuck here for days trying all kind of method but it just wont work. :(

```
Query query_1= reference.child("Users").child("Room")
                .child("Profile");

query_1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        //ACTIVITY 1

                Query query_2 = reference.child("Users").child(Room)
                        .child("Receiver").child("id");

                query_2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            //ACTIVITY 2

                            Query query_3 = reference.child("chatrooms").child("Room")
                                    .child("Creator").child("id");

                            query_3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //ACTIVITY 3


                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: are u retrieving anything?

Comment: Please add your database structure and tell us what exactly are you trying to get.

Comment: Sorry already solved, referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659569/wait-until-firebase-retrieves-data