# Using Image url from firebase to make slideshow

Tags: android, firebase, url, arraylist

I tried to recover four photos from firebase and display them in a slide show, retrieving the url's using `getUrl()`.

However, the `setSliderViews()` method does not execute and I see this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main:"

How can I resolve this problem ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Upload data;
    ArrayList<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
    SliderLayout sliderLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sliderLayout = findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);

        sliderLayout.setIndicatorAnimation(SliderLayout.Animations.FILL); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.Animations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
        sliderLayout.setScrollTimeInSec(1); //set scroll delay in seconds :
        getUrl();
        setSliderViews();
    }
    private void  getUrl(){

        final ArrayList<String> mUrl = new ArrayList<String>();

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("upload").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    data = snapshot.getValue(Upload.class);

                    if (data != null) {
                        mUrl.add(data.getImageUrl());
                    }
                }
                url = mUrl;
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void setSliderViews() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

            SliderView sliderView = new SliderView(this);
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        sliderView.setImageUrl(url.get(0));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        sliderView.setImageUrl(url.get(1));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        sliderView.setImageUrl(url.get(2));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        sliderView.setImageUrl(url.get(3));
                        break;
                }


            sliderView.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //sliderView.setDescription(" " + (i + 1));
            final int finalI = i;
            sliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(new SliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSliderClick(SliderView sliderView) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is slider " + (finalI + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            //at last add this view in your layout :
            sliderLayout.addSliderView(sliderView);
        }

    }

    }
```

[This screen from lolcat describe error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAst9.png)

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: I'm not understand your question ?

Answer (score 1):

the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` does not execute right away so by the time your `setSliderViews()` is called the 'url' ArrayList is empty. you need to wait for the listener to execute.

Check out this thread:
[wait until firebase retrieves data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659569/wait-until-firebase-retrieves-data)