# Firestore/Android Studio: Null Object Reference - Getting Cloud Values to Class and working with it in Main Activity?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I really hope, you can help me here:

I'm trying to create a Class "Cloud" where all the Firestore-Stuff is happening.

But I can't overwrite Attributes with Firestore Values and work with them in my Main-Activity.
It will always give me a Null-Object-Reference-Error.

**Example**

Inside my Cloud-Class I have an Attribute "theTest".
With the Method "Test()" I now want to overwrite this Attribute with a Value of my Firestore Database:

```
   public String Test(){
    db.collection("Products").whereEqualTo("isAvailable", true).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            theTest = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).getId();
        }
    });
    return theTest;
}
```

Now in my Main-Activity, I want to use this value just like:

```
String test = cloud.Test();
Log.d("TheTest", test);
```

But it's not working! I always get the same Null Object Reference Error.

I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong..

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the `null` value is that retrieving data from Firebase is an async function. So, it won't fetch your value and then proceed to return. It will first return `theTest` which is null at that point and then go back to the `onSuccess` when it's done.

You need to somehow work inside your `onSuccess` method, so you'll need to wait for your query to finish in order to get `theTest` value and not the null value. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997517/14759470) explains how to wait for Firebase to fetch data and then proceed.

But as suggested in the answer in that question:

> Don't use Firebase as functions that return values - it goes against it's asynchronous nature.
>
> Plan code structure that allows Firebase to perform it's task and then
> within the closure (block) go to the next step.
>
> In your code, for example, change the function to not return anything
> and within the onDataChange, as the last line call the next function
> to update your UI.

Try to implement a different approach to get this value.

Comment: Ahhhh this makes sense! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding!